# How to append a character while using the conditional statement in sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

I need to set the `href` value depending on the nullity of `sling:vanityPath`. The `hit.properties.sling:vanityPath` returns the string value for `sling:vanityPath` property. I need to append a `/` before the `hit.properties.sling:vanityPath` value. Is it possible to do that in the following code or do I have to test it twice, but that comes with code repetition?

```
<a href="${hit.properties.sling:vanityPath == null? hit.path : hit.properties.sling:vanityPath @ extension='html'}"/>
```

Comment: you can try string manipulation like this: 

<sly data-sly-test.vanityPath="${hit.properties.sling:vanityPath && '\{0}' @ format=[hit.properties.sling:vanityPath]}"></sly>
<a href="${vanityPath || hit.path @ extension='html'}"/>

.I haven't tested though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenation or binary operators are not supported in HTL. You can either use [prependPath](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#125-uri-manipulation) or double test for the slash.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it in one line. But you can try defining a variable for the concatenated value instead of duplicating code for the a tag. Also, do you have to check for null specifically? can't you just reverse the conditions and check if the value exists?

```
<sly data-sly-test.concatenatedURL="${['/', hit.properties.sling:vanityPath] @ join = ''}"/>
<a href="${hit.properties.sling:vanityPath ? concatenatedURL : hit.path @ extension='html'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ join to concat an array:

```
<a href="${hit.properties.sling:vanityPath ? ['/', hit.properties.sling:vanityPath] : hit.path @ join ='', 'extension='html'}"/>
```